# How to create a random login with Faker on Java

Tags: java, faker

I need to create a random user for autotests with Faker. For that I need to obtain a random login and password. How can I done it?

I suppose that for passwords I can use

```
faker.internet().password()
```

And I don't know what to do about login.

Comment: Is this library the one you're using? https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker

Comment: Exactly this one

Comment: If a login only consists of an email address and a password, you can use `faker.internet().emailAddress()` and `faker.internet().password()`. If you want a username instead of an email address, you can use `faker.internet().username()`

Comment: I've got only `faker.internet().userAgent()` method. No userName

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that, you have to use `faker.name().username()`, not internet.

Comment: You're welcome, added it as an answer so future visitors will find it easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to use an email address along with a password:

```java
faker.internet().emailAddress()
faker.internet().password()
```

If you would like to use a username along with a password:

```java
faker.name().username()
faker.internet().password()
```